# Nested UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm fairly new to iOS development and I want to make something like the **attached screenshot**.

[image]

I've read the nested UINavigationControllers is not a good idea, if not impossible, so I'm more than willing to accept ideas on how to implement what I want.

On my second screen there are two views I want to switch back and forth between (**NOT using gestures and push animated**), while maintaining a static header and footer.

The only way I know how to do a push segue is with a UINavigationController, hence why I see the need for nested ones.

How do I implement this? I thought that in my second UIViewController I could programmatically create a UINavigationController and add it to self.view, but I ended up doing this:

```
self.subNavigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[someVC alloc] init]];
[self.view addSubview: self.subNavigationController.view]
```

But that only adds the view of self.subNavigationController to self.view, not self.subNavigationController itself.

Like I said, I could easily be way off base on how I should be handling it, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you understand the concept of a UINavigationController.

Comment: Is the middle thing like a photo browser thing or something? I.e. where you have content that you can change? How do you want to change between the content screen? Is the data in them hierarchical?

Comment: I agree @max_, can you offer more assistance?

Comment: @Fogmeister, nope. I was hoping it would be a UIViewController that has to UIViewControllers - one is a map and one is a UITableView (it's for displaying items either on a map or in a list view).

Comment: A UINavigationController is mainly used to move up and down a hierarchical system. i.e. Countries - Football Leagues - Teams. It provides the bar along the top of the screen with the back button. Sounds like you might want this at the root of your app. The Map/Table screen that you want sounds more like a UITableViewController. A UITabBarController provides a bar along the bottom of the screen for switching tabs. Each "tab" is a UIViewController. You can place this inside a UINavigationController so you navigate to the tab bar controller and then tab between the table and the map.

Comment: I'll give the UITabController thing a shot, that might take care of it. Feel free to make your comment an answer @Fogmeister and if it suits my needs I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @Fogmeister - As I mentioned in my question, I want to use a push segue between the mapview and list view, UITabBarController can't accomplish this.

Comment: When you say you want to use a push segue. Do you mean you want the map to slide off and the tableview to slide on? i.e. the animation. You can do this with a UIScrollView. You're not actually using a segue at all for this. Just have a paginated UIScrollView with the two view (map and table) each with their own view controller but displayed on the UIScrollView. You can even disable touch scrolling and have a button trigger the scroll for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, if I've got this right then what you want is an app where you can navigate between different views (like any other app).

This will use a `UINavigationController` (lets call this "nav1") and this is the bit that you're OK with.

However, you also want a view that will have a static navigation bar. i.e. as far as nav1 is concerned this is only a single part of the navigation through the app. It also wants to have two potential views in there. (the map and the table view) and it will have a static bar along the bottom too (in IB this is a ToolBar I think). Lets call this the "mapAndTableViewController".

You haven't said exactly how this works but you don't want swipe gestures between them. So I'm guessing you will have a button or something to swap between them?

Something like this...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eg6vWGh67zk&feature=youtube_gdata_player

The way I've done this is to use a single view controller with a scroll view. On the scrollview set scrolling disabled and set paging enabled. This sounds odd but this removes the touch scrolling from the scrollview while still allowing code access.

Now, in the `mapAndTableViewController` you populate the left and the right hand side of the scroll view.

What you do here is now take the two view controllers... `mapViewController` and `yourTableViewController` and instantiate them. Then add the views of these controllers in to the scrollview left and right sides accordingly.

Essentially you will have THREE view controllers. One for the scroll view, one for the map view and one for the table view.

Without any further explanation from you I can't really help beyond this as I don't fully understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Bingo, you got it! I have two buttons in my static header view to switch between the two sub UIViewController's.

Comment: Ha, took me a while to get my head round it but got there eventually :)